# How was the obsolete character ㅿ pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, hangul

The character ㅿ is now obsolete. How was it pronounced when it was used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can't tell for sure, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul#Obsolete_letters) puts it at either [z] (like in 'zoo'), or [ʝ̃], which would be a nasal version of [ʝ].

To pronounce [ʝ̃], say [j] like at the beginning of 여기 (or English 'yes'), but constrict airflow even further to create more turbulence (turning it from an approximant into a fricative) and nasalize it.

Comment: Can you say a few more words about the methodology here? When did ㅿ become obsolete, and which traces of it have survived that allow us to infer the approximate pronunciation?

Comment: Constricting airflow and nasalizing it made the sound "느~여기." Am I doing this right? Hahaha

Comment: @DanielMietchen Post it as a new question and I'll add a few historical details.

Comment: @Dono done: http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-can-we-infer-the-pronunciation-of-now-obsolete-hangul-characters .